# Running OFX Plugins

Tags: c++, c, openfx

I am starting a new project at the university I attend to develop OpenFX plugins for video editing software. I currently own Sony Vegas Pro 13, Edius, Premiere, and HitFilm 3 Pro. In order to test any OpenFX program, I have to open the dll in one of my video editing software applications.

**Question:** Are there any lightweight applications that I can easily run and debug openFX applications (dll files)?

I am new to OpenFX (not programming), so any tips about OpenFX would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try to use http://www.tuttleofx.org/. It includes several useful utilites.